# The order of pytest tests execution inside the modules is reversed. How do I set it right?

Tags: python, pycharm, pytest

I know, by default, the tests will be executed in the order they are defined in the class/module. But, in my case, it is reversed. How shall I set it right.

Sample Code:

```py
def test_a():
    assert True


def test_d():
    assert True


def test_c():
    assert True
```

The order of execution is:

```
test_demo4.py::test_c PASSED                                                                                                                        
test_demo4.py::test_d PASSED                                                                                                                        
test_demo4.py::test_a PASSED
```

So, how do I reset to default execution order? I couldn't figure out a way to do this.

Comment: Why does it matter which order they're run in? Dependency on the order of the tests is a smell.

Comment: What testing framework are you using? Do you want to order tests alphabetically or in the a,d,c order?

Comment: Do you have any pytest plugins installed? Some of them change the test order. Apart from that - @jonrsharpe is right, the order should not matter except in some special cases. It may even be a good idea to use a plugin like `pytest-randonly` to find unwanted test dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the cause which reversed the pytest's test execution sequence.
I had installed the `pytest-depends` package to learn the possibilities of using it. Uninstalling `pytest-depends` restored pytest's sequential test execution.

Thank you @MrBean Bremen for your insights.